# error handling speech_recognition WaitTimeOutError

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

when i tried to run this code

```
  import speech_recognition as sr  #importing sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("speak into mic")
    audio = r.listen(source,timeout=2)


try:
    print("Transcription:" + r.recognize_google(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Audio Unintelligible")

except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("cannot obtain results : {0}".format(e))

except sr.WaitTimeoutError as k :
    print("time out")    #error handler for time out error
```

when i run the above code it giving error like this

```
speak

 into mic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/punna/PycharmProjects/alex/alex.py", line 6, in <module>
    audio = r.listen(source,timeout=2)
  File "C:\Users\punna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 544, in listen
    raise WaitTimeoutError("listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start")
speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError: listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start
```

I wrote exception but it is again giving error

can anyone help me

Comment: The stack trace mentions the offending line is `audio = r.listen(source,timeout=2)`, so if you want to handle that exception, you should wrap that line in a `try / except` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you kept the timeout for a limited amount of time. Try without the timeout or keep the timeout at least more than 5

Comment: I tried it for 6 seconds it is giving error as same no change

Comment: i just want to stop the process if the user not talk within 3 seconds

Comment: or instead, try

Comment: without the timeout

Answer (score 1):

This might help I have just added the return "none" Statement so that it returns a none if something goes wrong and I also added phrase_time_limit to 5 and query = r.recognize_google(voice,language='en-in') this statement to recognize the words spoken by the user into a variable instead of this statement print("Transcription:" + r.recognize_google(audio)) then it worked try this might help you

```
 r = sr.Recognizer()
 with sr.Microphone() as audio:
     speak('Listening...')
     r.pause_threshold = 1
     voice = r.listen(audio,timeout=1,phrase_time_limit=5)
 try:
     print("Thinking...")
     query = r.recognize_google(voice,language='en-in')
     print("Transcription:"+query) 

 except Exception as e:
     print("I am Sorry There is an error while i am recognizimg your command")
     return "none"
 return query
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.

Comment: This might help I have just added the return "none" Statement so that it returns a none if something goes wrong and I also added phrase_time_limit to 5 and query = r.recognize_google(voice,language='en-in') this statement to recognize the words spoken by the user into a variable instead of this statement print("Transcription:" + r.recognize_google(audio)) then it worked try this might help you

Answer (score -1):

```
def takecommand():
    try:
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Listing.......")
            r.pause_threshold = 1
            audio = r.listen(source, timeout=1, phrase_time_limit=5)
    except Exception as e:
        speak("error in my files sir restarting")
        speak("completed")
        return "none"

    try:
        print("Recognize......")
        qureay = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print("user said:" +qureay)

    except Exception as e:
        speak("Say That Again Please...")
        return "none"
    return qureay
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31517628)